# Vertical Align in a Fixed Nav CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the verical align of a menu. I have tried to center it vertically with the margin, vertically-align but there is no result.

Here comes the HTML code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-rocket fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <ul>
</nav>
```

CSS code:

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 3rem;
    background: #292929;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto 1rem;
}

nav ul li i {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}

nav ul li i a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Web's photo with this code:

https://gyazo.com/d520c343ceffce688bf3e4333e9f2fba

What i need:

https://gyazo.com/07217a263738281885e3a0fe8053a152

It must be centered over the red line.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If that's your actual code, it's probably because you haven't closed the list. `<ul><ul>` should be `<ul></ul>`. If not, then set `line-height` on the `li`, since the nav height is fixed.

Comment: There are already many answers about this on StackOverflow. You can use flexbox align-items center, table with vertical align middle, line-height, padding, margin..